# How to add scopes to id token from api scopes

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I have two app registrations in Azure:

1. A client application (Web) that can issue id- and access tokens and has all scopes from the API added.
2. An API registration that knows the web application and exposes some scopes to it.

In the manifest of the API registration I defined some user roles. Those roles are assigned to users in the corresponding enterprise application.
All access tokens for that API that are issued by the web application contain those roles and my APIs can authorize in this way.
But my SPA has only the id token that does not know those roles.
My approaches to solve this issue are:

1. I could just let my SPA parse the access token and extract the roles. But this is not recommended by MS, so I dont want to do so - even though it would work.
2. I could also send the access token to one API endpoint, that could parse the token and return the roles for me. This is already nicer, but I still do not like this approach.

Is it somehow possible to include the roles from APIs in the ID tokens that a web application issues? If I put roles in the manifest of the web application itself, those roles appear in ID tokens.
But I do not want to have redundant roles in API and web application manifest.
What is a suitable approach to solve my problem?

Best would be to include all API roles also in the ID tokens issued by the web applications. But I could not find any way to do so...

Answer (score 1):

What you are running into is the 2 sources of data in an OAuth architecture, and your UIs and APIs will generally need to work with both types:

- Generic central data such as user id, name, email, scopes
- Application specific data such as roles, preferences, authorization rules

Option 2 of your above approaches is by far the preferred method in most cases:

- UI sends access token to an API endpoint such as GET /api/userclaims
- API can return whatever claims the UI needs
- It is easy to change over time, for multiple UIs and APIs

Using claims in your API is the way to tie the two sources of user data together, without needing to put all of the claims in tokens. A couple of blog posts of mine explore this topic further:

- [User Data Management](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/)
- [Claims in APIs and UIs](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)